# Connection of orthogonal decomposition of Hilbert space and with eigenspace of linear operator on Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

We know that $L^2(S^1)$ is Hilbert space. Also
$$-i\frac{d}{dx}:L^2(S^1)\to L^2(S^1)$$
is linear operator on that. Also $-i\frac{d}{dx}e^{ikx}=ke^{ikx}.$

So each $k$, $e^{ikx}$ is eigenvector.
Define
$$H_k=\{f\in L^2(S^1):-i\frac{d}{dx}f=kf \}$$
Due to eigenspace $H_k$ for different $k$ are orthogonal.
We also know that $f\in L^{2}(S^1) $ is written in the Fourier series.

$$f(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\hat f(k)e^{ikz} $$
That is $L^2(S^1)=\oplus_{k\in \mathbb Z} H_k$.

Is such a phenomenon occur for all Hilbert spaces? What would be the choice of operator?

Also,
if we consider $C^{\infty}(S^1)$ space, on that we can define operator and that space is dense in $L^2(S^1)$. Our operator is self adjoint also closed. Can there is any spectral decomposition theorem for closed self adjoint operator defined on dense set.
I wanted to link this with more general $L^2(M)$ Hilbert space.

Any help/hint/reference will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your operator is not well-defined. Its domain should be the Sobolev space $H^1(S^1)$. Then it is well-defined and self-adjoint. The point here is that this self-adjoint operator (let's call it $A$) has a compact resolvent, i.e., $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is a compact operator for any $\lambda\notin\mathbb R$. For these operators it is always true that the closed linear span of its eigenspaces coincides with the whole space.

Comment: I have one doubt. If we consider $C^{\infty}(S^1)$ space, on that we can define operator and that space is dense in $L^2(S^1)$. Our operator is self adjoint also closed. Can there is any spectral decomposition theorem for closed self adjoint operator defined on dense set.

Comment: No, that operator is NOT self-adjoint. It is only symmetric. "Can there is any spectral decomposition theorem for closed self adjoint operator defined on dense set" - Not with eigenvalues. Consider the bounded operator $T$ in $L^2(0,1)$ mapping a function $f$ to $xf(x)$. It does not have any eigenvalues. However, you can always use the spectral measure of a self-adjoint operator to spectrally decompose space and operator.